# How can I share variables across functions?

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables

I am working on a program where the user enters two usernames and I wanted to validate the usernames in a separate function. Currently, when I press the return button, I get absolutely nothing, I assume this is a global variable problem.

Many thanks

```
def play_game_login():
    global pl
    pl = Tk()


#Setting window parameters
pl.title("Login Form")
pl.geometry("300x250")
pl.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")
Label(pl,width="300", text="Please enter two usernames below", bg= "#315399",fg="black").pack()

global playerOne
global playerTwo
playerOne = StringVar()
playerTwo = StringVar()

Entry(pl, textvariable=playerOne).place(x=120,y=42)
Label(pl, text="Username One * ").place(x=20,y=40)

Entry(pl, textvariable=playerTwo).place(x=120,y=82)
Label(pl, text="Username Two * ").place(x=20,y=80)

Button(pl, text="Continue", width=10, height=1, bg="#4169e1",command=lambda:[play_game()]).place(x=105,y=130)
Button(pl, text="Return", width=10, height=1, bg="#4169e1",command=lambda:[pl.destroy()]).place(x=105,y=160)


    
def play_game():

one = playerOne.get()
two = playerTwo.get()


#Presence Check
if one=='' or two=='':
    message.set("Please ensure all credentials are input!")
elif one == two:
    message.set("Please ensure usernames are different!")
else:
    message.set("Users Registered!")


play_game_login()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. You have code that looks like it should be indented inside the functions, but it isn't.

Comment: The `Return` button ends the game, it doesn't call the function that validates the entries. That happens when you click the `Continue` button.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what your code is trying to accomplish, and I have fixed a few bugs, highlighted by comments in the code below.

As for the global variance problem, the Entry widgets needed to be globalized in order for them to be called by another function. The names of one and two can be saved to a global variable so that you can call them anywhere. (I placed them in the list [users]).

For the "Return" button, I don't quite understand its purpose. The "Continue" function can validate the names, and then a successful validation can initiate the rest of the game.

```
from tkinter import *
users = [] # You can store the user names here in a global list, see append commands at the bottom of the code

def play_game_login():
    global pl
    pl = Tk()

    #Setting window parameters
    pl.title("Login Form")
    pl.geometry("400x250")
    pl.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")
    Label(pl,width="300", text="Please enter two usernames below", bg= "#315399",fg="black").pack()

    global playerOne
    global playerTwo
    global message1, message2 # <-- Globalize these in order to be able to call them outside of the function
    playerOne = StringVar()
    playerTwo = StringVar()

    message1 = Entry(pl, textvariable=playerOne)
    message1.place(x=120,y=42, width=225) # <-- the .place command must be on a different line in order for
                                          # you to be able to reference the object later
    Label(pl, text="Username One * ").place(x=20,y=40)

    message2 = Entry(pl, textvariable=playerTwo)
    message2.place(x=120,y=82, width=225)
    Label(pl, text="Username Two * ").place(x=20,y=80)

    Button(pl, text="Continue", width=10, height=1, bg="#4169e1",command=lambda:[play_game()]).place(x=180,y=130)
    Button(pl, text="Return", width=10, height=1, bg="#4169e1",command=lambda:[pl.destroy()]).place(x=180,y=160)

def play_game():

    one = playerOne.get()
    two = playerTwo.get()


    #Presence Check
    message1.delete(0,END) # <-- Each operation must be performed on both <message1> and <message2>
    message2.delete(0,END)
    if one=='' or two=='':
        message1.insert(0, "Please ensure all credentials are inputed!")
        message2.insert(0, "Please ensure all credentials are inputed!")
    elif one == two:
        message1.insert(0, "Please ensure usernames are different!")
        message2.insert(0, "Please ensure usernames are different!")
    else:
        message1.insert(0, "Users Registered!")
        message2.insert(0, "Users Registered!")
        users.append(one) # <-- Save the user names to the global list
        users.append(two)


play_game_login()
```

I hope that this helps, and best of luck on your game!

Comment: Thank you for the help! - The return button just executes another function in which I didn't need any help for. After using your code and entering some details I always receive "Please ensure all credentials are Input" even though there is some characters that have been typed into the entry box - Would could be causing this?

Comment: Currently, the contents of the two message boxes are compared in the same if statement, so if either of the two entry widgets is empty, the "Please ensure all credentials are Input" result appears. To prevent this, you could separate the if statements to check each box separately. Best of Luck!